# Undefined index: inc_social_context

Tags: wordpress, plugins, undefined

I'm working on this wordpress plugin settings page and I have debug mode turned to true while i'm getting this **Undefined index: inc_social_context**

I don't know what I have done wrong, here are my code:

```
public function kankozfgp_post_type_display_html ( $content ){
$kankozfgp_options_global = get_option( 'kankozfgp_option_name' );
$kankozfgp_inc_social_context = esc_attr( $kankozfgp_options_global['inc_social_context'] );

if ( isset( $kankozfgp_inc_social_context ) && !empty( $kankozfgp_inc_social_context ) ) {
            $kankozfgp_inc_social_context = "true";
        } else{
            $kankozfgp_inc_social_context = "false";
        }
}
```

Here is the callback function

```
public function kankozfgp_inc_social_context_cb( $args ) {      
    $kankozfgp_options_global = get_option( 'kankozfgp_option_name' );
    ?>

    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['label_for'] ); ?>" 
    data-custom="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['kankozfgp_custom_data'] ); ?>"
    name="kankozfgp_option_name[<?php echo esc_attr( $args['label_for'] ); ?>]"

    value="1"<?php echo isset( $kankozfgp_options_global[ $args['label_for'] ] ) ? ( checked('1', $kankozfgp_options_global[ $args['label_for'] ] ) ) : ( '' );

 ?>>
</input>

    <?php
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the offending line:

```
$kankozfgp_inc_social_context = esc_attr( $kankozfgp_options_global['inc_social_context'] );
```

You are trying to assign an index value to a variable that does not exist.

Later in your code you check if the value exists:

```
if ( isset( $kankozfgp_inc_social_context ) && !empty( $kankozfgp_inc_social_context ) ) {
            $kankozfgp_inc_social_context = "true";
        } else{
            $kankozfgp_inc_social_context = "false";
        }
}
```

But it's too late, you need to check before you assign it.

This is what I would do:

```
$kankozfgp_inc_social_context = isset( $kankozfgp_options_global['inc_social_context'] ) ? true : false;
```

Comment: This works perfect. Now that i'm not using esc_attr on the variable, is there a security issue with that?